# What does the word "succeed" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs

Please help me figure out the meaning of the word "succeed" in the following text:

> [So recruit all five nefarious members (they’re a quintet in the game) and reach 200,000 team power. **Succeed** and you’ll relish raid and arena battles like never before!](https://apps.apple.com/us/story/id1484138776)

The text is from the description of the game "Marvel Strike Force".

Does the word "succeed" simply mean "be successful" here?

Comment: That meaning fits: be successful at the recruiting and gaining 200k rep. Often the simplest answer is the answer. What else could *succeed* mean here? Is there any other context which could alter what it applies to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succeed in the sentence means to achieve the result/goal.
Here is the proper definition acquired:
"achieve the desired aim or result:
*he succeeded in winning a pardon.*"
-> Oxford Dictionary of English.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known and much used idiom, in which the imperative of a verb is stated, followed by a description of the likely outcome, if you choose to follow it:

***Succeed** and you will lead a happy life*.

***Watch** and you will see what I mean*.

***Hurry** and you will see the procession pass by*.

***Ask** and you will be informed*.

***Seek** and ye shall find*.

etc.